# Why did Guri leave Prince Xizor?

Tags: star-wars

I thought Guri's objective was the safety of Prince Xizor, yet she left him to fight Luke, leaving Xizor in danger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She gives the answer right there in the book:

"My master pits himself against those who can challenge him. No man is my equal in combat; except, if the stories are true, a Jedi Knight." (apologies if the quote is slightly off, I don't have the book with me right now)

Guri knows that her presence or absence at that moment cannot help Xizor. She cannot speed his journey to his escape vessel, nor is even she fast enough to get to the sub-basement and deactivate or dispose of the thermal detonator Lando Calrissian has set to destroy Xizor's palace. And surrounded by guards and travelling in a different direction to Skywalker, Princess Leia, Chewbacca, Lando, and Dash Rendar, Xizor is highly-unlikely to come across any physical danger. Even if he does, he's more than capable of defending himself against most agressors, as he proves earlier in the book by killing an assassin with his bare hands.

What Guri can do, however, is take revenge against the man who is responsible for her master's change in fortunes. Killing Skywalker will also accomplish her master's goal of killing the young Jedi to gain revenge over Darth Vader for the death of his family years earlier, simultaneously discrediting Vader in the Emperor's eyes and furthering his own political ambitions.

There are many good reason's for Guri to leave Xizor's side - she does this regularly, after all, as she's as much a travelling enforcer as a personal bodyguard - but the best is also the simplest; she desires challenges, as she states earlier in the book before destroying a rival shipping concern at Xizor's request. Xizor discusses with her how he himself desires challenges, intentionally pitting himself against opponents - Skywalker, Leia Organa, and even Lord Vader himself - who could potentially defeat him. He risks his own life because it's more thrilling to risk death for gain than to live in a safe bubble. As Guri says after that conversation; "Ah, this is why you eat moonglow (the poisonous fruit, roughly analogous to eating poisonous puffer-fish on Earth)." She seeks challenges, and only Skywalker can possibly challenge her.